# how to run wso2 esb and api manager in one jvm

Tags: wso2

can I have any way to merge esb (wso2 enterprise service bus) and api manager to run in one Carbon app?
I want to use different wso2 products, like esb and api manager, identification server, business rule server. 
But I don't want to run them in different carbon application. This needs lots of resources. 
I know if I want to merge them, I must let them in same carbon version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to run all products in a single carbon server? If so, you need to install API Manager feature in wso2esb.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. But from file structure, I am not sure how to do it. Also I can try to install features, but not sure how it works. Do you have any document for me to follow

Comment: in the document, it has lots of feature, but when I try to install by url [link] (http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/2.3-introducing-schema.html), very few features can be installed